# Media in Wordpress is being indexed as its own page

Tags: wordpress

My client is wondering why media items in WordPress are being indexed as their own pages ie. http://www.michaelphamlaw.com/logo-v2/

It appears as if only certain media uploads are doing this. Now I know that WordPress creates content URLs for media items but am not sure why it is creating fully functioning webpages with headers and footers for them. I am at my wits ends and have been searching google most of the afternoon with no luck. Has anybody ran into this before? If so how did you fix it?

Normally this would not be an issue especially because they do not show up in the Pages menu under the WP-Admin screens. But they appear on Google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing [image attachment pages](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-attachment-pages/). It's not a mistake. There are [ways to remove them](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-image-attachment-pages-in-wordpress/) if you'd like.

Comment: I definitely came across that link and followed the instructions as I am using Yoast SEO. But when I went to those pages after applying the changes the still showed up. Does it take some time?

Comment: I would think it'd be applied instantly. You might go to your permalinks and just re-save those settings. You don't need to change anything, just hit save. The other thing you might look at is whether the ones that are showing up on pages are un-attached images (images not embedded in pages). That may be the issue w the Yoast fix. It seems to rely on a parent page. You could test that by sticking an unattached image in a test post and seeing if the page remained after that.

Comment: Okay, I will definitely try that I downloaded one of the plugins mentioned at the end of the article and that worked! Thank you for your help!